# php - Chrome does not detect UTF-8 on first load

Tags: php, google-chrome, utf-8

It happens only in Chrome, and doesn't matter if is a computer, tablet or phone.
When I load a page in Chrome it shows:

```
NARA - CosmÃ©tica Natural
```

When I reload, cames the correct:

```
NARA - Cosmética Natural
```

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` ?

Comment: ^yep, what @SergeyChizhik said, you're not specifying a charset in the headers, and chrome takes a guess, a wrong guess, OR you're sending the wrong charset in headers.

Comment: Is the first line after  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: You can see it in nara dot es but only in Portugal or with a portugese Proxy